# How can I execute WHERE IN syntax SQL by Solr 8.7

Tags: mysql, sql, solr

I want transform the following SQL query to a solr query

```
select 
    Sentences.sentenceid, sentence, languagecode 
from 
    Sentences 
where 
    sentenceid in (select translatedid 
                   from SentencesRelationship 
                   where sentenceid = '3152');
```

Thanks you so much!

Comment: try using fq in your query

Comment: That would map to what Solr calls a join: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/other-parsers.html#join-query-parser

Comment: @MatsLindh Could you mind demo Join Query Parser for my case?. I'm not clear
 about `q  = {!join from=id to=manu_id_s}compName_s:Belkin`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have two SOLR cores:
1. sentences (sentenceId, sentence, languageCode)
2. sentencesRelationship (sentenceId, translatedId)

With the following data:

sentences:

```
sentenceId, sentence, languageCode
1, sentence1, lang1
2, sentence2, lang2
3, sentence3, lang3
```

sentencesRelationship:

```
sentenceId, translatedId
1, 101
2, 102
```

There are several solutions to make a join in SOLR. One would be to use the innerJoin in a StreamingExpression:

```
innerJoin(
    search(sentences, q="*:*", fl="sentenceId, sentence, languagecode", sort="sentenceId asc", qt="/export"),
    search(sentencesRelationship, q="sentenceId:3152",
               fl="sentenceId, translatedId", sort="sentenceId asc", qt="/export"),
    on="sentenceId"
)
```